# SharePoint CAML not returning checked out files

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, ssom

I have a CAML query to find documents by name within a document library, however, the checked out (drafts) documents are not found by the below query (ran with high privilege):

```
Spquery query = new Spquery(){
RowLimit = 1,
Query = "<WHERE><EQ> <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='Text'>file_name.txt</Value> </WHERE></EQ>
};
```

What I am missing, how can I include the checked out items ?

Comment: When you say checked out files you mean the files which are never checked in to the system or the files which were checked in some time before and then checked out?

Answer (score 1):

Try substitute Type="Text" to Type="File", to be like this:

```
<WHERE><EQ> <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='File'>file_name.txt</Value></WHERE></EQ>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
         <Value Type='File'>file_name.txt</Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>
```